# jXchange - How To Get Started?

Tags: web-services

[jXchange](http://www.jackhenrybanking.com/Default.aspx?P=465d93c4-539e-4570-809d-9e1607b6b2ed) is apparently some sort of Web Service made by a company called [Jack Henry](http://www.jackhenrybanking.com/). It's used for (I'm assuming) talking to your core AS400 system.

I've quite literally found *nothing useful* for documentation on how to get started using this.

**Does anyone have experience with this and can direct me to a good starting point?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can email a request for help to VendorQA@jackhenry.com if you are working for one of our customers licensed to jXCHANGE.  We do have vendor documentation available provided that you are sponsored by a JHA customer.

Comment: That's too bad - It's unfortunate you can't learn the system before you pay for licenses, documentation, etc...